# install Eloquent orm without composer

Tags: php, orm, eloquent, slim

I install slim without use composer before , can I install Eloquent  by manual too? I can't find any tutorial related...

```
<?php    
require 'usr/local/vendor/Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$projectDir = 'usr/local/project';   

spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
  $class_name = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class_name);

  $file = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$class_name.'.php';

  if (is_readable($file)) require_once $file;
});

$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'templates.path' => 'usr/local/project/view',
    'debug' => true,
    'log.enabled' => true
));
```

/index.php
/usr/local/project/controller
/usr/local/project/model
/usr/local/project/view
/usr/local/project/route.php

/usr/local/vendor/Illuminate/.. package clone from github

Comment: By using composer you will save yourself from many headaches.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that?

Comment: @MikaTuupola  I can't change install slim by manual that's not my idea, but I'm using composer install Eloquent now and inside `/usr/local/vendor/vendor`  it works but just seems weird so I'm looking is there possible install Eloquent by manual..